# Pegar valor input com jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Estou tentando pegar o valor de um `input` e um `textarea` com jquery mobile e adicionar os valores dentro de uma `div` usando `append()` só que não está funcionando? 
alguém consegue me dizer onde estou errando?

O `input` e a `textarea` estão dentro de um `panel` e quero adicionar os valores setados nele no `content` da pagina principal.

```
//Html da pagina principal que está dentro de data-role="page" e o id dessa page é id="index"
<section data-role="content">
        <h3>Todas as tarefas</h3>
        <div class="list">

        </div>
    </section>

//Inicio do Panel
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-display="overlay">
        <h4>Nova Tarefa</h4>
        <label for="tarefa">Adicionar Tarefas</label>
        <input type="text" id="tarefa" placeholder="Remédio, Mercado e etc...">
        <label for="detalhe">Detalhes</label>
        <textarea id="detalhe" cols="1" rows="1" placeholder="Exemplo: tomar remédio 'x', comprar leite e etc..."></textarea>
        <button type="button" id="btn" data-icon="check">Salvar</button>
    </div>

$( document ).on( "#index", function() {
    var nextId = 1;
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var tarefa = $('input#tarefa').val(); //já tentei input[id=tarefa] e (#tarefa).
        var detalhe = $('textarea#detalhe').val(); //já tentei input[id=detalhe] e (#detalhe).
        nextId++;
        var content = "<div class='item" + nextId "'>" + tarefa + '</div>';
        $('.list').append(content);
    });
});
```

Comment: `$( document ).on( "#index", function() {`? qual é a ideia desta linha?

Comment: pelo que pesquisei o documento tem que iniciar com este comando assim como o jquery inicia com $(documento).ready()

Comment: Nõ será `$(document).on("pageinit", "#index", function() {` ou `$( document ).on("pagecreate", "#index", function() {` ? podes testar?

Comment: Sergio, tentei os 2 e não funcionou, se puder dar uma olhada no código eu agradeço. https://github.com/Alkun/lembrete-app

Comment: Onde estás a correr/carregar esse código? não vejo no HTML o código nem o ´<script src="...` a chmar esse código... https://github.com/Alkun/lembrete-app/blob/master/index.html#L8-L9

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o código funcinou com a linha `$(document).on("pageinit", "#principal", function() {` e eu havia esquecido de carregar o meu código Js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [método `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) precisa de um *evento* no primeiro argumento. Está a faltar o *evento* que faz disparar essa função *callback* no *elemento* `#index`, muda o código para:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){
```

Outra coisa que te falta é incluir o ficheiro `.js` onde esse código está para ele ser carregado. O teu código:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1,"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
   <title>minha app</title>
</head>
```

falta-lhe `<script src="js/meuJs.js"></script>`, junta isso depois da linha o jQuery mobyle.